# Node.js: Async fs.writeFile queue is creating race condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to use `async` with node.js to handle multiple incoming POST requests to edit a JSON file.  No matter how I refactor it, it will always make one of the edits and not the other.  I though that using `async.queue` would force the operations to handle sequentially?  What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
var editHandler = function(task, done) {

    var req = task.req;
    var res = task.res;

    fs.stat( "./app//public/json/" + "data.json", function(err, stat) {
        if(err == null) {
            console.log('File exists');
        } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
            console.log("Error");
        } else {
        console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
        }
    });
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log(req.body);

    fs.readFile( "./app//public/json/" + "data.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       data = JSON.parse( data );
       data[req.params.id] = req.body.school;
       //console.log( data );
       fs.writeFile("./app//public/json/" + "data.json", JSON.stringify(data), function (err){
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
       })
       res.redirect('/');
    });
};

//Make a queue for the services
var serviceQ = async.queue(editHandler, 20);

serviceQ.drain = function() {
    console.log('all services have been processed');
}

app.post('/edit_school/:id', function(req, res) {

   serviceQ.push({req: req, res: res }) 

})
```

Thanks in advance for any insights!  I am really new to using node.js for anything other than npm/webpack.

Comment: The [docs](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) say that  *Tasks added to the queue are processed in parallel (up to the concurrency limit).* So you might try changing 20 to 1 and see how that turns out.

Comment: Also [Nodejs docs for stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) state that : *Using fs.stat() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not available.* I think you can basically get rid of the `stat` call in your `editHandler` function

Comment: @jrook Thank you for the quick reply!  I set the value to one and my console logs show me only the first form's info.  If I have the value set to higher than 1, it shows both, or more, up to the limit.  I think that's also a limit of how many tasks can be packed in a queue.  I removed the file check, but it had no effect.  Some times my JSON breaks and has a bit of extra code at the end which is the same number of characters as the difference in the edits (ie I remove or add the word 'school' and end up with 6 extra characters. That's why I think it's a race condition.

Comment: By *race condition*, what do you mean exactly? It seems you want each user's `school` value from a POST response to be appended to a file. Is that correct?

Comment: I mean it's like both POST requests and the edits they contain are being done at the same time and only one gets through.  If I add a setTimeout it actually works now. But that feels...wrong.  Surely there is a way to make this work without resorting to setTimeout.

Comment: In `editHandler` function, what `done` is supposed to do?

Comment: Basically, after writing the file, you want to go back to the calling function (through `done` callback) not do a `res.redirect` inside `fs.write`. You can try that and see if it helps!